# Visual Studio Code not displaying any output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have some code here

[image]

I'm simply trying to run, the code, by clicking the Code Runner extension button in the top right corner. Except, when I click that, the only prompt I receive in the terminal is

```
/Users/Nick/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/Nick/Desktop/cam_reddish_data.py
```

With no return output. I am using the correct version as my interpreter. I also recently installed anaconda, and am trying to run from that environment, so maybe that's the issue?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ***The real reason why***

It is because actually that command:

```py
player = player.get_player("Cam", "Reddish", just_id=False)
```

keeps executing and stops the next lines of code to be excuted, even if you removed that command, hello will be printed in the console. Check if there is any problem in that command

Answer (score 2):

This way you are not actually running any code.

There are two ways you can run it:

1. Navigate to your directory with the command cd (changedirectory)

   `cd`

   `cd /Users/Nick/Desktop`

   Then run your program with python by typing:

   `python cam_reddish_data.py`
2. Run the program without navigating to your directory:

   `python ~/Desktop/cam_reddish_data.py`

Lmk.

Samu